# How to get the status of an application in WebSphere from java client application?

Tags: web-applications, websphere, status

I am working on an java client application, that has to check whether an application (it is not a web application) on WebSphere is up and running? Does anybody has idea how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a web application, send a HTTP request to it. You may need to set a dummy JSESSIONID to get routed to the right backend JVM if you cannot access it directly.

I'd suggest creating a dedicated resource that checks the overall health of your app and publishes a simple response.

You really don't want to be using administrative API's remotely to see if websphere thinks your application is running when you can check so easily with HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately It is not a web application, otherwise I would really send HTTP request and would not bother anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JMX to remotely access the WebSphere server and query it's application state.

Instructions for accessing JMX for traditional WebSphere are here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tjmx_programming.html

This page provides a complete example of different administrative tasks:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tjmx_develop.html

Instructions for accessing JMX for WebSphere Liberty are here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_admin_restconnector.html

Hope this helps, Andy